# Debugging a production asp.net application locally

Tags: asp.net, remote-debugging

I made an asp.net application on my development box which was deployed on production.
  I can see my application on production URL with public domain such as https://www.myapp.com ( sample).

Is it possible to debug the application by attaching the process using from my Visual studio development environment by following - Go to debug and then attach the process by selecting the browser displaying https://www.myapp.com ?

I tried it and its attaching the process but it does not hit the debug points in VS2010 . Can anyone please let me know if its possible to do this way ?

Thanks in Advance!  Junni

Comment: This link can help you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817659.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are just debugging your browser.  If you want to debug a remote machine you need a debug version of your code running on that machine and MSVSMON.EXE running on the remote machine.  You would be best servered by reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx
then researching MSVSMON questions here.